# uploading files asynchronously in ASP.NET (AsyncFileUpload and flash controls not suitable)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, file-upload

I have looked at various options for uploading files asynchronously in ASP.NET. the default Microsoft control does full postback, AsyncFileUpload control has only one button and cannot change the text and appearance and I need two buttons browse and upload. not interested in flash based controls. I found this http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti.html close to what I need. it uses iframe to achieve this, but I would like a simplified version of this. I just want to display an image while uploading, I don't need number of bytes transferred etc. how can I achieve this? I just need to upload the file asynchronously without page flickering and save the file to the server and update the page contents after the upload is complete.

Comment: Could you explain why flash is not acceptable?  We use YUI2 uploader and it is relatively flexible, but uses some flash elements (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe JQuery uploadify would work for you: http://www.uploadify.com/

We've used Telerik's version and that has everything you  want I believe, and it works very, very well, but its a paid version then.

HTH.